# How do you count the number of times a source has been cited in a document?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Say you have a document with many citations and you want to see the number of times each one is cited. This could be implemented without much effort in a programming language, but I have a feeling this might be possible with `biblatex`.
The ideal solution would add the number of times a source is referenced as an extra column in the bibliography. Can this be done?